# Scala: warning: 1 deprecation (since 2.13.0); re-run with -deprecation for details

Tags: scala

I am currently learning Scala and using VS Code as my IDE, for every simple script I run i get this error:

```
warning: 1 deprecation (since 2.13.0); re-run with -deprecation for details
```

I saw a couple similar questions but they focused on sbt and the answers didn't really help.

This is the code I ran:

```
    object Demo{
    def main(args:Array[String]){
        println("Hello World")
    }
  }
```

I just installed Scala -> `Scala code runner version 2.13.2 -- Copyright 2002-2020, LAMP/EPFL and Lightbend, Inc.`

Java:

```
java version "12.0.1" 2019-04-16
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 12.0.1+12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 12.0.1+12, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I dont understand what it means by re-run with -deprecation, not very clear how to run it.

Thank you.

Comment: It's about compiler arguments. How do you build your code? Through sbt?

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok No I haven't got sbt, maybe I should download it and use that instead?

Comment: You should have some way of defining compiler options. It you have a build tool consult how it support passing compiler options, if it's IDE, then it should also have some way of doing it, but from your question it's hard to guess what you use.

Comment: It you use Scala Metals VS code plugin, then you are using sbt to build things, but you are most likely relying on empty sbt project with all things set to defaults. You would have to create `build.sbt` file in the root of your project to edit parameters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's about compiler arguments. I assume it's about deprecated [procedure syntax](https://scalacenter.github.io/scalafix/docs/rules/ProcedureSyntax.html), so instead

```
object Demo {
  def main(args:Array[String]){
    println("Hello World")
  }
}
```

it should be

```
object Demo{
  def main(args:Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("Hello World")
  }
}
```

I would be clearer if you passed `-deprecation` as compiler argument. Assuming you use sbt it would be something like:

```
scalacOptions += "-deprecation"
```

if you have single project or something like

```
val someProject = project.in(new File("someProject"))
  .settings(
    scalacOptions += "-deprecation"
  )
```

if you have multiple project or if you use use `project`s for any other reason.